# troubleshooting raspberry pi pigpio error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

i installed the `python-pigpio` library and get the error `pigpio.error: ‘GPIO is not in use for PWM’` when running the line https://github.com/danking6/smart-led-window/blob/master/window.py#L133. google didn’t turn up much for that error, and am new to raspberry pi development. im not sure where to even start troubleshooting. i am only using pins 21 and the ground pin next to it. can someone point me in a good troubleshooting direction….

using python 2.7.16, python-pigpio 1.68-3

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving your connection to pin GPIO 18? according to [this](https://www.electronicwings.com/public/images/user_images/images/Raspberry%20Pi/RaspberryPi_PWM/Raspberry%20pi%203%20PWM%20pins.png) image, pin 21 does not have PWM support